# Multivariate imputation in R

Tags: outliers, data-imputation, data-preprocessing

I am working with a dataset from the world bank, it's a relatively simple dataset with 11 variables for 211 countries from 1990-2015:

```
iso2c (0 missing)
iso3c (0 missing)
country (0 missing)
year (0 missing)
life_expect (604/5486 - 11% missing)
population (15/5486 - 0.27% missing)
birth_rate (506/5486 - 9% missing)
neonat_mortal_rate (546/5486 - 9.5% missing)
region (0 missing)
income (0 missing)
gdp_percap (538/5486 - 9.8% missing)
```

I wish to identify countries for the year 2014 which are outliers in the data but to do so I need to do something with the missing values, either delete entire countries or impute some of the missing values but obviously deleting data results in information loss.

I don't know why the data is missing so I can't definitively say it's MCAR, MAR or MNAR.

By filtering down the year the 2014 the missingness for each of the variables changes to the following values:

```
iso2c (0 missing)
iso3c (0 missing)
country (0 missing)
year (0 missing)
life_expect (14/211 - 1.9% missing)
population (1/211 - 0.5% missing)
birth_rate (14/211 - 6.6% missing)
neonat_mortal_rate (21/211 - 10% missing)
region (0 missing)
income (0 missing)
gdp_percap (27/211 - 12.8% missing)
```

Is the best approach to impute these values to use some sort of clustering technique or should I impute the values from the entire dataset (all years) or should I drop those countries with missing values?

Is the best approach to use the Mahalanobis' distance to identify multivariate outliers, using this approach assumes the multivariates are normally distributed. What happens if this is not the case and my kurtosis and skew indicate left or right skewed data?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgkBr1CkDf7dklJTDJiSVQxVVU/view?usp=sharing) is a link to the dataset I am using in CSV format, if anyone could give me a steer as to how best to impute these values and ultimately to identify the outliers I would be very grateful.

Comment: I can't see that imputation will add any information on outliers to what you have already. In this kind of data there are outliers -- China and India have very big populations, etc. -- but their main implication is to work with some variables on log or another transformed scale. Why worry about marginal normality or its lack?

Comment: Thanks Nick, so if asked about outliers for 2014 you would remove any records with blanks and perform a typical interquartile analysis to highlight outliers? Would a mahalanobis analysis highlight the outliers?

Comment: I wouldn't ever throw out incomplete observations personally. I don't find either what I guess you mean by  "typical interquartile analysis" or Mahalanobis measures useful for this kind of data. You need subject-matter expertise,  willingness to work on transformed scales and modelling that accommodates outliers, not throws them out. The population of China is a simple example of how outliers are likely to be genuine.